# How to write openssl engine

Tags: linux, openssl

I want to write an openssl dynamic engine, but I can't find any document for that.

My algorithm that I want to write, is a chipper algorithm(like rsa) and a hash algorithm (like md5).

Is any simple engine source code that I can change that and use from that?

Comment: Late but possibly relevant for someone else: [Developing an engine for OpenSSL](http://sinodun.com/2009/02/developing-an-engine-for-openssl/).

Comment: For all the seekers, a better example is now to find on the OpenSSL Wiki
with Sources attached: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Creating_an_OpenSSL_Engine_to_use_indigenous_ECDH_ECDSA_and_HASH_Algorithms good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is any simple engine source code that I can change that and use from that?

The Intel `RDRAND` engine is pretty easy to understand. You can find its sources with:

```
openssl-1.0.1f$ grep -R -i ENGINE_rdrand *
crypto/engine/eng_rdrand.c:static ENGINE *ENGINE_rdrand(void)
crypto/engine/eng_rdrand.c:    ENGINE *toadd = ENGINE_rdrand();
```

Here's how you can load and set it as the default random number generator engine (from [Random Numbers|Hardware](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers#Hardware)):

```
unsigned long err = 0;
int rc = 0;

OPENSSL_cpuid_setup();
ENGINE_load_rdrand();

ENGINE* eng = ENGINE_by_id("rdrand");
err = ERR_get_error();

if(NULL == eng) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ENGINE_load_rdrand failed, err = 0x%lx\n", err);
    abort(); /* failed */
}

rc = ENGINE_init(eng);
err = ERR_get_error();

if(0 == rc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ENGINE_init failed, err = 0x%lx\n", err);
    abort(); /* failed */
}

rc = ENGINE_set_default(eng, ENGINE_METHOD_RAND);
err = ERR_get_error();

if(0 == rc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ENGINE_set_default failed, err = 0x%lx\n", err);
    abort(); /* failed */
}

/* OK to proceed */

...
ENGINE_finish(eng);
ENGINE_free(eng);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do

```
apt-get source openssl
```

That will give you the openssl source code. Within the tree you can find for example the directories crypto/rsa and crypto/md5 which I guess would be a good start for your project.
It also comes with some documentation in form of READMEs and the like.

Have fun.

Comment: can i use them in dynamic engine mode?

Comment: To me it looks like it. Have a look at README.ENGINE. It says:
In addition, dynamic binding to external ENGINE implementations is now
  provided by a special ENGINE called "dynamic". See the "DYNAMIC ENGINE"
  section below for details.

Comment: ok, i see. but how to write engine to load with dynamic engine. is any sample engine to compile and load to test?